# PHP: How to detect "magic_quotes" parameter on runtime?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using a shared host server which I can't control.
The PHP is initialized with the `--enable-magic-quotes` parameter so I must use `stripslashes` to retrieve unescaped `$_GET` parameters.

The problem is that I cannot detect this behavior at runtime (PHP 5.4.41):
all of these functions return "false":

```
ini_get(magic_quotes_sybase)
get_magic_quotes_gpc()
get_magic_quotes_runtime()
```

Is there any way I can detect on runtime, without changing server configuration, whether I need to use `stripslashes` or not?

**EDIT** I use WordPress platform, my own PHP code is quite minor.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-gpc.php In PHP 5.4, magic quotes no longer exists. `get_magic_quotes_gpc()` and related functions _always_ return false, and you can be assured your environment doesn't have it.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware to PHP 5.4 issues, but it appears that if you use the `--enable-magic-quotes` flag the `magic-quotes-gpc` is turned on (and, apparently, there is no way to detect this in runtime).

Comment: Do you see that documented somewhere that it can be reenabled at compile time? According to any other documentation I have seen, regardless of the compile flag the feature has been entirely removed and cannot be enabled. http://php.net/manual/en/configure.about.php

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not familiar with PHP. But now I found a [note](https://forum.directadmin.com/showthread.php?t=42353) saying that `--enable-magic-quotes` should be completely ignored in PHP 5.4, so now I don't have a clue why I need to `stripslashes`.

Comment: Are you certain that the original raw `$_GET` values are escaped, and you are not seeing output values modified elsewhere in code?  If you `var_dump($_GET);` immediately before any other code runs, are you seeing escaped values?

Comment: Yes I am sure, I will send a code sample later. I also have to mention that I use Word Press. Does it make any difference? maybe WP changes the `$_GET` variables?

Comment: WordPress may change them, it would not surprise me. I don't know much about WP though.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go

`get_magic_quotes_gpc()` Returns 0 if magic_quotes_gpc is off, 1 otherwise. Or always returns FALSE as of PHP 5.4.0 because it no longer exists as of PHP5.4.0

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $lastname = stripslashes($_GET['lastname']);
} else {
    $lastname = $_GET['lastname'];
}
```

> I have to admit thats a complete ripoff from the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-gpc.php)

As magic_quotes were removed as of PHP5.4.0 you might want to do this instead :

```
if (function_exists("get_magic_quotes_gpc") && get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $lastname = stripslashes($_GET['lastname']);
} else {
    $lastname = $_GET['lastname'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I saw this at manual but I couldn't understand it. Since I use PHP 5.4, the second clause is executed but on the other hand I need to `stripslashes` the string...

Comment: So why bother testing anything, just run  stripslashes()

Comment: I don't know PHP well and stripslashes details. This can be a solution but my concern is what will happen if the host will remove the `--enable-magic-quotes` flag in the future, and this call would come redundant? Wouldn't it create new bugs?

Comment: See extra suggestion in answer

Comment: `get_magic_quotes_gpc()` returns `false` so these two suggestions are logically equal.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use .htaccess try

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a shot. I use WordPress - should I edit .htaccess it in WP main dir?